# Feeding YOLOv4 image data into LSTM layer?

Tags: natural-language-processing, long-short-term-memory, pytorch, yolo

How would one extract the feature vector from a given input image using [YOLOv4](https://github.com/Tianxiaomo/pytorch-YOLOv4) and pass that data into an LSTM to generate captions for the image?

I am trying to make an image captioning software in PyTorch using YOLO as the base object classifier and an LSTM as the caption generator.

Can anyone help me figure out what part of the code I would need to call and how I would achieve this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the extracted features coming out of YOLOv4 and save it to pickle file and use them for later.

You can also find related information in this project made by Jason Brownlee

https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-a-deep-learning-caption-generation-model-in-python/